# javascript readAsArrayBuffer returns empty Array Buffer

Tags: javascript, arraybuffer, audiocontext

I am trying to read a local file using the FileReader readAsArrayBuffer property.
The read is success and in the "onload" callback, I see the Array Buffer object in reader.result. But the Array Buffer is just empty. The length is set, but not the data. How do I get this data?

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <input type="file" id="file" />
</body>

<script>
    function handleFileSelect(evt) {

        var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

        var selFile = files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            console.log(e.target.result);
        };

        reader.onerror = function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        };
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(selFile);
    }


    document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>

</html>
```

the console output for reader.result

```
e.target.result
ArrayBuffer {}
e.target.result.byteLength
25312
```

Can anyone tell me how to get this data?
is there some security issue? 
There is no error, the onerror is not executed.

*From comments:* Can you please let me know how to access the buffer contents? I am actually trying to play an audio file using `AudioContext`... For that I would need the buffer data...

Comment: Why do you think the buffer is empty? Your code does not actually access/inspect the buffer contents at all. Maybe you're confused by the `console.log` output? `console.log()` will not print the contents of the buffer.

Comment: Thanks nmaier, I thought the same...but I don't know how to access the buffer contents...
Can you please let me know how to access the buffer contents?
I am actually trying to play an audio file using AudioContext...
For that I would need the buffer data...
Many thanks for your help

Comment: You're using the onload event instead of the onloadend event. Your code will work if you replace the onload event by onloadend. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Comment: @seb it was not the issue. The file that I was using was corrupted...

Please check my replies to nmaier below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, playing a sound using the `AudioContext` stuff isn't actually that hard.

1. Set up the context.
2. Load any data into the buffer (e.g. `FileReader` for local files, `XHR` for remote stuff).
3. Setup a new source, and start it.

All in all, something like this:

```
var context = new(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

function playsound(raw) {
    console.log("now playing a sound, that starts with", new Uint8Array(raw.slice(0, 10)));
    context.decodeAudioData(raw, function (buffer) {
        if (!buffer) {
            console.error("failed to decode:", "buffer null");
            return;
        }
        var source = context.createBufferSource();
        source.buffer = buffer;
        source.connect(context.destination);
        source.start(0);
        console.log("started...");
    }, function (error) {
        console.error("failed to decode:", error);
    });
}

function onfilechange(then, evt) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        console.log(e);
        then(e.target.result);
    };
    reader.onerror = function (e) {
        console.error(e);
    };
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(evt.target.files[0]);
}


document.getElementById('file')
  .addEventListener('change', onfilechange.bind(null, playsound), false);
```

See this live in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P8ENK/), which works for me in Firefox and Chrome.

I threw in a `console.log(new Uint8Array())` for good measure, as browser will usually log the contents directly (if the buffer isn't huge).
For other stuff that you can do with `ArrayBuffer`s, see e.g. the [corresponding MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays).

Comment: I also did the same thing, but was getting an error while playing the sound...
The fiddle you have given me also gave the same error. Below is 

**console output**

`ProgressEvent

now playing a sound, that starts with 
Uint8Array[10]

failed to decode: null`

Comment: Maybe you're trying to load some file format that isn't supported? Not all browsers (on all platforms) support all audio formats. As I said: I tested this fiddle in Chrome and Firefox (29 and Nightly) on OSX 10.9 and it works for me.

Comment: Oh no, I get the problem, 
I tried playing an mp3 file and ogg file.
They seem to be corrupt. I download from the same site where i was trying to find some audio context examples...
I was trying so many alternatives, thinking some problem with the code, it just wasted my whole day...
I will try playing some other file and see if it works...

Comment: Yup, with some other file it works...
So bad I feel :(
Thanks nmaier for your time, highly appreciate it

Comment: This drove me nuts.  Finally I found that you can't access the array buffer in the result directly.  instead data = new Uint8Array(reader.result) takes care of it.

Answer (score 8):

Here is how to read array buffer and convert it into binary string,

```
function onfilechange(evt) {
var reader = new FileReader(); 
reader.onload = function(evt) {
  var chars  = new Uint8Array(evt.target.result);
  var CHUNK_SIZE = 0x8000; 
  var index = 0;
  var length = chars.length;
  var result = '';
  var slice;
  while (index < length) {
    slice = chars.subarray(index, Math.min(index + CHUNK_SIZE, length)); 
    result += String.fromCharCode.apply(null, slice);
    index += CHUNK_SIZE;
  }
  // Here you have file content as Binary String in result var
};
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(evt.target.files[0]);
}
```

If you try to print ArrayBuffer via console.log you always get empty object {}

Comment: How would you convert binary string to array buffer